# What is a good English translation for the proverb "La mentira dura, mientras la verdad llega"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, méxico

Please critique my translation: “A lie survives till the truth arrives.” I want to use it as an epigraph (in a book), so it needs to sound punchy in English too.

Comment: "Enter the truth, leaves the lie" 
"Enter the truth, the lie leaves"
(sounds like inspired by a _Metallica_ song but I like it)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to best express a concept in the English language. You should ask at http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rsanchez indeed, we are not supposed to translate sentences into other languages apart from Spanish, because we are not experts in those other languages. But we can certainly explain Spanish words, sentences and concepts. Maybe the question just needs to be rephrased and not closed.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que hay variedad de formas de decirlo; sin embargo, aquí hay algunas opciones dependiendo de lo que desees.

1. Traducción literal sacada de [*A Dictionary of Mexican American Proverbs*](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=39-sWW7QvUYC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=la%20mentira%20dura%20mientras%20la%20verdad%20llega&source=bl&ots=IBjfVAOWWv&sig=YJ74Pn0zIsTSVzSlvOQPqIXjxi0&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj10trSxr_NAhXSth4KHQHvAbk4ChDoAQgoMAI#v=onepage&q=la%20mentira%20dura%20mientras%20la%20verdad%20llega&f=false):

> The lie lasts while the truth arrives.

2. Traducción menos literal sacada de [*Word Magic*](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/diccionario/en-es/you%20can%20lie%20while%20the%20truth%20shows%20up.php):

> You can lie while the truth shows up.
>
> A lie lasts as long as the truth does not surface

3. Una cita atribuida a Mark Twain:

> A lie can travel halfway around the world while the truth is putting on its shoes.

Sin embargo esta última se aleja un poco del significado a dar de la oración original en español.

4. Un refrán en inglés que hace referencia al contraste entre la mentira y la verdad:

> A lie stands on one leg, truth on two.

Esta última guardando algo del significado del original. Un símil entre que puedes mentir/avanzar en una pierna hasta que la verdad llega/alguien que anda en dos avanzará más que tú.

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks!!  The first two (using "while") don't really make sense in English (in my opinion).  "A lie lasts as long as the truth does not surface" does make sense, but it's not very punchy. I love #4. Perhaps I could couple it with the proverb, while making clear it is not a direct translation. Do you know of a Mexican proverb about how one lie leads to another -- lies breed lies?? That would fit really well too, but I can't find a proverb expressing exactly that idea.

Comment: @AmyThernstrom They do make sense in English. However, it isn't exactly the same meaning that would convey an expression such as *You can lie until the truth shows up*. I just kept the original quotes for obvious reasons. As for a proverb that conveys the idea of *one lie leads to another*, perhaps *to hide a lie, a thousand lies are needed*.

Answer (score 2):

I found these two [here](http://www.quotegarden.com/honesty.html) that may suit you:

> - A lie has speed, but truth has endurance. ~Edgar J. Mohn
> - A lie may take care of the present, but it has no future. ~Author Unknown

**Edit to improve:**

[Swahili Proverbs](http://swahiliproverbs.afrst.illinois.edu/lying.html):

> - *Ukweli ukidhihiri uwonge kajisetiri*.  JKP.        When the truth appears, untruth hides itself.
> - *Kweli inapofika uwongo hujitenga*.  MEM.165.   When truth arrives, falsehood yields.